# как сделать так что бы когда нажимаешь на букву E на клавиатуре тогда что бы число появилось от 1 до 10

Tags: python, клавиатура, числа

как такое сделать на pyhton подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Поэтому пожалуйста, делайте [минимальный, самодостаточный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), который мы можем запустить у себя и воспроизвести проблему. Так же изучите [как создавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Совершенно непонятно, что вы хотите - с какой целью и в каком контексте.

Comment: import keyboard

def print_pressed_keys():
    print((0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))

keyboard.wait('e')
print_pressed_keys()

Comment: вот это как я хотел только тут бы немного изменить что бы код выводил без запятых и без кавычик но это я уже в другом вопросе напишу

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос задан очень размыто, если я вас правильно понял, то возможно вам нужно это:

```
import random
import keyboard

def print_pressed_keys():
    print(random.randint(0,10))

keyboard.wait('e')
print_pressed_keys()
```

Comment: Можно же и без функции, просто print-ом.

Comment: @magistar тоже верно, да ладно, пусть будет так

Comment: Попробую как вы сказали. Спасибо большое